# how to add radial-gradient property on img element

Tags: html, css

i want to add radial-gradient on an  element, it works when i set an image as a background image but not on  element. Is there any way to do this, what am trying to achieve here is fade the image from bottom.

```
*My Code*
<div class="slideBanner">
    <img src="/media/{{show.banner}}" style="background: red radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0,0,0,0) 10%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 90%); background-blend-mode: multiply; width: 500px; height: 500px; z-index: 1;">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your image here as well?

Comment: Also, this is a really informative page for you to scour how to do that with images. They provide the CSS as well: https://dev.to/obinnaogbonnajoseph/a-practical-guide-on-radial-gradient-css-2383

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that your answer is like this [codepen-resolve](https://codepen.io/jasbel/pen/pogBepV)
[codepen-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USF0l.jpg)

```css
.slideBanner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
.slideBanner:before {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
background: red radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0,0,0,0) 10%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 90%); 
 background-blend-mode: multiply; width: 500px; height: 500px; 
 z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
  }
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="slideBanner">
    <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2hrW2w5l99U/XYuD2fDHydI/AAAAAAAAIKY/Wu_bQmABRL0-lm9LAt3tzs75uKT8S0nhwCKgBGAsYHg/s320/15694239854007711595824302455034.jpg" >
</div>
```